# How does Druid spell preparation & casting work?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, druid

I just want to make sure I have ALL of this correct.  Let's I'm a moon druid at level 3.

My druid has: 2 cantrips, 4 level 1 spell slots, and 2 level 2 spell slots.

Assuming a Wisdom of 16, I can prepare wisdom mod (+3) + level (3) per "instance" (before doing a long rest) which means that I can *prepare* 6 different spells.

I can choose any combination of 6 spells from the level 1 and 2 list since I only have level 1 and 2 spell slots.

I can cast the same spell *as many times as I want* (like I can cast *goodberry* (a lvl 1 spell) technically 6 times (4 level 1 spell slots, and 2 level 2 spell slots). The level 2 slots will increase the damage of course.

I could only cast *spike growth* (a level 2 spell) 2 times, because I cannot cast it as a level 1 spell.

I could do a long rest and re-prepare 6 more spells and my spell slots would all be refreshed.

Is this correct? Am missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a spell be prepared once and cast multiple times?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44736/can-a-spell-be-prepared-once-and-cast-multiple-times)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## You have it all basically correct

> So I can prepare wisdom mod (lets say +3) + level per "instance" (before doing a long rest). (So I can prepare 6 spells)

Yes, you would have 6 spells prepared each day.  However, you get your spell slots back and you get to re-prepare spells *after* a long rest, not before.  You would need to complete the entire long rest before you prepared new spells and got your used spell slots back.

> I can choose any 6 spells out of the level 1 and 2 list (since I only have level 1 and 2 spell slots)

Yes, there are no restrictions on which spells you can prepare, so you can prepare all level 1 spells, all level 2 spells (although that isn't a very good idea with only 2 level 2 slots), or any combination of the above.

> I can cast the same spell as MANY times as I want (like I can cast goodberry (a lvl 1 spell) technically 6 times (4 level 1 spell slots, and 2 level 2 spell slots). The level 2 slots will increase the damage of course.

Mostly correct.  Not every spell increases in potency when cast at a higher level.  In fact, the Goodberry spell you mentioned does not get any better when cast using a level 2 spell slot.  Many do, but some do not.  Keep that in mind and make sure to read the spell description before you use it in a higher level.  To be clear, you absolutely CAN cast a low level spell in a higher level slot, however if there is no additional benefit for casting the spell in a higher level slot (as per the spell description) then you may not be optimally using your limited spell slot resources.

> but I could only cast spike growth (a level 2 spell) 2 times, because I cannot cast it as a level 1 spell.

Exactly.

> I could do a long rest and re-prepare 6 more spells and my spell slots would all be refreshed.

Yes, with one minor caveat.  Keep in mind that Rules-As-Written, it is not the *player* that decides to take a long rest, but the *DM/GM* that decides if a long rest is available.  Make sure you know how your DM is running the game, because you cannot initiate a long rest without DM approval, and that may determine how you use your spells and which spells you prepare.

Comment: While true, can you support your answer by citing evidence from the rules?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why I struggled with this but it finally clicked for me.  Maybe it had to do with everyone (including the player's handbook) using a Wisdom of 16 for their examples.  Basically there are three aspects to this:

1. Number of spell slots (quantity of spells one can cast at each level before resting), which is 100% static based on level
2. Number of spells that can be prepared (dynamic based on Wisdom and level)
3. Casting spells at a higher level even though it was prepared as a lower level spell

So for a level 3 druid that has a Wisdom of 18:

1. **Forever and always, this druid can only cast up to 6 spells before requiring a rest** (4x 1st level and 2x 1st/2nd level spells)
2. **Because of the high Wisdom, this druid can choose 7 spells to "prepare"**.  It could be 7 2nd level spells or 7 1st level spells but ideally would be a logical combination of both.

   A good example for this druid would be to prepare 4x 1st level (with 1 or 2 of them able ramp up to a higher level) and 3x2nd level spells.  As these spells are cast, they are still "prepared", which means that even though I prepared 7 DIFFERENT spells, I could cast 1 of the 1st level spells 7 times.  I could also cast 1 of the 2nd level spells twice, which would "fill" both the 2nd level slots that are available to me.  Therefore I could not cast any more 2nd level spells.

For a level 3 druid with a Wisdom of 10:

1. **Still can cast 4x (1st) and 2x (1st or 2nd) spells but...**
2. **Because of the average Wisdom, this druid can only "prepare" 3 spells.**  This means the choice of those 3 become much harder because the druid can cast 6 times choosing from just those 3 spells to fill 4x 1st and 2x 2nd slots.  So I would think that choosing 2x 1st level (with at least 1 and ideally both of them able to ramp up) and 1x 2nd level would make the most sense.

Example:

1st level

- Cure Wounds (can fill a 1st level or 2nd level slot when casting)
- Entangle (can only fill 1st level slot)

2nd level

- Flame Blade (this can also fill higher level slots once they become available)

During the day the druid will ideally cast 6 times using these three spells to fill 4 first level slots and 2 second level slots.
Examples:

1. Cast Entangle 6 times
2. Cast Entangle 4 times and Flame Blade 2 times
3. Cast Entangle 4 times and Cure Wounds 1 time (as level 2 spell) and Flame Blade 1 time
4. Cast Cure Wounds 4 times (as level 1 spell) and Cure Wounds 2 times (as level 2 spell)
   etc.

I hope this helps anyone else that might be having difficulties grasping the concept of casting/preparation/spell slots and how they are affected by your Wisdom modifier.  Finally, as a long-winded response to your question, YES, everything you said is accurate but I hope my exhaustive response and additional examples provide further insight.

*Note: All of this is a result of my interpretation of the rules defined in the 2014 5e D&D Player's Handbook (phb) p.66 "Preparing and Casting Spells" and p.201 "Known and Prepared Spells/Spell Slots".*

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Can you support some of your statements by citing the rules? While your answer seems to be right, it would be improved by supporting your claims with evidence.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct, spell slots are regenerated at the end of a long rest and you can prepare new spells at the end of a long rest as well.

Comment: While true, can you support your answer by citing evidence from the rules?