# When choosing new spells to prepare, can divine spellcasters choose different cantrips?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, cantrips

Divine spellcasters can select a different group of spells to prepare each adventuring day in conjunction with a long rest. Does this include cantrips too? Or are they stuck with the ones they selected upon character creation/level up?

Comment: Have you read the spellcasting rules for clerics? This is answered explicitly in there. Could you elaborate on what about those rules is confusing to you?

Comment: At least related: "[Can certain classes replace cantrips with other spells when they level up?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/115973)" and "[How to allow cantrips to be changed](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/68718)" and "[Can characters, or at least Sorcerers, actually change out cantrips?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138545)" and "[Can druids change their starting cantrips each day?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/156134)" and "[Has there been an errata that allows cantrips to be swapped out upon levelling up?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/167862)"

Comment: @ThomasMarkov the linked question is basically "can I change cantrips when I level up", and this question is "can I change cantrips after a long rest", hence, not a dup.

Comment: @enkryptor changed the dupe target(s).