# How many wizard spells can I cast?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard

We just started playing D&D we are huge noobs and have problems with the wizard.
I'm a level 2 Wizard with 3 level 1 Spellslots.
Now the rulebook says:

> You prepare the list of wizard spells that are available for you to
>   cast. To do so, choose a number of wizard spells from your spellbook
>   equal to your Intelligence modifier + your wizard level (minimum of
>   one spell).

Does that mean I can prepare for example Magic Missile 5 times? So I can cast it 5 times before the next rest?
Or can I only cast it 3 times because I have only 3 level 1 spell slots??

Comment: What is your intelligence score?

Comment: closely related, if not duplicate: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/44736/23970

Comment: @Rubiksmoose 16

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that you choose 5 distinct spells from your spellbook to have "prepared"--those that you've got ready to cast that day. Each prepared spell you can cast if you have a spell slot available.

Think of the prepared spells as spells you have available that day, and the spell slots as "charges" that are used to cast them. If you prepare *magic missile* along with *alarm, burning hands, charm person,* and *chromatic orb,* then those are the L1 spells available to you that day. You have 3 "charges"--slots--to use to cast any of those spells. You could cast *magic missile* three separate times and no other spells, or *magic missile* once and *alarm* twice, or any other combination of up to three castings.

This is described both in the class description and a little more broadly on PHB p.201, "Spell Slots." It's a quirky bit of how D&D's magic works, called "Vancian casting," that takes a bit of getting used to.