# Can a sorcerer cast the same spell twice if enough spell slots are available?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, spell-slots

In D&D 5e, let's say that I have two level-1 spell slots available and want to cast Burning Hands. On one turn, I use one of the available spell slots to cast Burning Hands. On my next turn, I have one additional spell slot available. Am I allowed to use it for Burning Hands, or do I need to select a different spell to use the remaining spell slot?

I am asking this because I was told by someone more experienced that it doesn't work that way, but I thought the rules said otherwise.

Comment: Extremely related (it doesn't cover known spells but does this answer your question?): "[Can a spell be prepared once and cast multiple times?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44736)"

Comment: @devinbost: Does the linked question match yours? If not, you may want to edit your question to focus on whether a question can be learned once and cast multiple times in general, unless you (or the "more experienced" person) indicated there was something specific to sorcerers about this issue. The question might also be clarified by figuring out if the "someone more experienced" was talking about prepared spells (and D&D 5e), and by pointing to the relevant rule you're still confused about.